# kernel compile and menuconfig

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I am a newer in linux and using ubuntu(4.4.0-64-generic) in vmware fusion. I am learning how to compile kernel. So, I downloaded the kernel(linux-4.4.52.tar.xz) from the kernel.org. But when I input make menuconfig, there are some errors.

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/src/linux-4.4.52# make menuconfig
```

> HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
>   In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/posix1_lim.h:160:0,
>   from /usr/include/limits.h:143,
>   from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed/limits.h:168,
>   from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7,
>   from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
>   from scripts/basic/fixdep.c:114:
>   /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/local_lim.h:38:26: fatal error: linux/limits.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>   scripts/Makefile.host:91: recipe for target 'scripts/basic/fixdep' failed
>   make[1]: *** [scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 1
>
>   Makefile:444: recipe for target 'scripts_basic' failed
>
>   make: *** [scripts_basic] Error 2

I have installed headers files and done everything I can do. Someone can help me solve this problem?

Comment: Which header files did you install?

Comment: linux-headers-4.4.0-31, linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic, linux-headers-4.4.0-62, linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic, linux-headers-4.4.0-64, linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic. These are all header documents I find in /usr/src.

Comment: But where does `/usr/include/linux` point to?

Comment: I think it points to 4.4.0-64-generic. Cause I typed rm -rf asm linux scsi, 
ln -s /usr/src/linux-4.4.0-64-generic/include/asm-generic asm
ln -s /usr/src/linux-4.4.0-64-generic/include/linux linux
ln -s /usr/src/linux-4.4.0-64-generic/include/scsi scs. The 4.4.0-64-generic is my current kernel version.

Comment: So does `/usr/include/linux/limits.h` exist?

Comment: The limits.h exists in /usr/include/limits.h. I can not go into the /usr/include/linux, that shows "bash: cd: linux: No such file or directory". But the /usr/include/ path has a "linux".

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/include/linux`?

Comment: Here is the output:  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Mar  5 21:17 /usr/include/linux -> /usr/src/linux-4.4.0-64-generic/include/linux

Comment: Does that directory exist? Does `/usr/src/linux-4.4.0-64-generic/include/uapi/` exist?

Comment: Yes, it has /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-64/include/uapi

Answer (score 0):

You symbolic link is wrong; `/usr/src/linux-4.4.0-64-generic/include/linux` is the wrong directory and must not be linked to `/usr/include/linux`.

The kernel has two sets of headers: kernel-internal headers, and user API headers. The latter are inside the `uapi` directory, and they are what user-space program should see.

When you are compiling your own kernel, you can install the user-space headers of that kernel with [`make headers_install`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/headers_install.txt).
When you are using your distribution's kernel, you can just (re-)install the appropriate package (in your case, `linux-headers-generic`), and that will do the right thing as long as you do not muck around with those files afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But when I execute the command make heardes_install_all or make headers_install in /usr/src/linux-4.4.52, it still has the error "linux/limits.h: No such file or directory". Am I going in the wrong way? What are the steps to fix this problem?

Comment: Don't mix the distribution's packages and your own customizations, unless you know what you're doing. Repair the package by reinstalling it.

Comment: You mean I should execute "make hearde_install" under /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic?

Comment: You have manually created your own symbolic link `/usr/include/linux`. You have to restore it to the original state somehow. (And `make` runs only from the kernel source, and only after compiling it correctly.)